# How to replace new value into an excel column for every iteration using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excels where I compare the excel columns with each other and replace one excels data into other through for loop iteration.

The issue I am facing here is after comparison, I wanted to copy one excels value into other for every iteration, which I am not able to get through

please check my code below:

Assume we have two excels stored in two Dataframes df1 and df2. Each excel has 7 columns [A,B,C,D,E,F,G]. I am comparing Column B of each excel and wanted to store column A values of 2nd excel into column F of first excel.

I tried copying but I was able to create new excel with result , but my aim is to copy it into the existing excel.

Check my code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import numpy as np
    
    df1=pd.read_excel('C:\Python_Pandas\Tested_2\Tested_On_VF322\VF322_V1_R1_PDT24_1A.xlsx',sheet_name=0)          
    
df2=pd.read_excel('C:\Python_Pandas\Tested_2\Tested_On_VF322\VF322_V1_R1_PDT24_1A_new.xlsx',sheet_name=0

)
    
    olddoc_id = df3['ID'].tolist()
    olddoc_seq = df3['Description'].tolist()
    
    newdoc_id = df4['ID'].tolist()
    newdoc_seq = df4['Description'].tolist()
    
    old_dict = dict(zip(olddoc_seq,olddoc_id))
    
    new_dict = dict(zip(newdoc_seq,newdoc_id))
    
    for olddoc_seq, olddoc_id in old_dict.items():
        for newdoc_seq, newdoc_id in new_dict.items():
            m = re.search(str(olddoc_seq),str(newdoc_seq))
            if m:
                old_dict[olddoc_seq] = newdoc_id
```

Here after irrespective of a match is found or not i want to copy newdoc_id(column A) into another column of df1(column F)

When I am trying to use df1['columnF'] = newdoc_id it only stores the last value in the entire column.

I also tried copying like this old_dict[olddoc_seq] = newdoc_id but its copying into a new excel.

I also tried excelwriter, but it is replacing entire excel.

So is there any way to do this please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use xlwings to do this.

Here is a simple code how to read xlsx file and change the value.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = app.books.open(r'D:\pycharm\data_science\test.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
print(sht.range('C2:C5').value)
df_orginal = sht.range('A1:C5').options(pd.DataFrame, expand='table').value
print(df_orginal)
df_orginal['RANK'] = df_orginal['RANK'] + 1
sht.range('C2:C5').options(transpose=True).value = df_orginal['RANK'].tolist()
print(sht.range('C2:C5').value)
wb.save()
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Here is the result.

```
(python3) λ D:/Miniconda3/envs/python3/python.exe d:/pycharm/data_science/test.py
[10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0]
         ID  RANK
NAME
A     111.0  10.0
B     222.0  11.0
C     333.0  12.0
D     444.0  13.0
[11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0]
```

By the way, the installation of xlwings maybe a bit difficult, but it's a good tool to operate excel files using python.
For more details, you can see the documents of xlwings:

https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html

https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html